is there any way on vSphere to run an Automation Script for Guest OS while booting up or just after VMware tools get installed?
So I am trying to run a script across all my machines on vSphere for all VMs as soon as they either boot or just after the VMware tools get installed. So far I could not find anything solid. Is there any way integrated within vSphere? It would be an added benefit if the output for that script could be displayed in the summary tab of the VM.
I tried going through ESXCLI but could not find any solution catering to my issue.
